# how to compare 2 different database column data type in java

Tags: java

In my case i have to compare column datatype of 2 different database.
the below is the sample code.

```
ResultSetMetaData metadataSrc = Src_rs.getMetaData(); // here Src_rs is source resultset
ResultSetMetaData metadataTar= Tar_rs.getMetaData();   // here Tar_rs is target resultset
int countSrc = metadataSrc.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i <= countSrc; i++) {
String srcOracleType=metadataSrc.getColumnTypeName(i);
String tarMySqlType = metadataTar.getColumnTypeName(i);
}
```

Here I want to check `srcOracleType` is equals to `tarMySqlType`. If it same I want to continue execution else needs return false.

This query begins when I have tried to create a table in MySQL and Oracle with datatype `int`. Through Java Jdbc code when I retrieve both database datatype, for oracle its gives `NUMBER` and for mysql it gives `LONG`.

Comment: By two different databases I mean MySql and Oracle here. I created table with a datatype as 'INT' in both ORACLE and MySql. Mysql creates a table with 'LONG' as the datatype for the same 'INT' while Oracle puts the datatype as 'NUMBER'.

Answer (score 1):

Extract from the API (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html):

```
getColumnTypeName(int column)
     Retrieves the designated column's database-specific type name.
```

You could use:

```
getColumnClassName(int column)
      Returns the fully-qualified name of the Java class whose instances are manufactured if the method ResultSet.getObject is called to retrieve a value from the column.
```

It would be easier by comparing the "conversion" in Java instead of comparing the database-specific row types.

Comment: i got fully-qualified name of the Java class like 'java.math.BigDecimal'  for oracle & 'java.lang.Integer' for mysql. Both is entirely different how can i compare this two. if both is same i have to do some business logic.

Comment: You can't directly, you would need an additional abstraction level such as "is number" by example.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late.

Confirm if the source number and the target number both map to the same quantity in your application domain. If they do not, they are not comparable.

If they do, then you need to find an effective java type using these rules:

1. If one of them is an integer data type (byte, int, short, int, log, big integer, boolean) and the other is a real data type (float / double / big double), then effective java sql type is the integer data type.
2. If both are of integer data type, then choose the one with a smaller range (eg: short has a smaller range than int).
3. If both are of real data type, then choose the one with a smaller range.

Convert both values to the effective data type (only one needs to be converted actually) and compare.